# Windows batch file copy based on format, "FILENAME_20131220.txt.pgp"

Tags: batch-file, ftp, copy

First post here :)  I am FTP downloading a bunch of pgp files from our partner.  I have a script to decrypt but only need to do so for the most recent file.  The file format is, "FILENAME_20131116.txt.pgp".  Since the files are all downloaded at the same time, date-time stamp can't be used.  Is there a way to copy the most recent so I can decrypt?  If not, would a Windows batch file allow me to FTP GET the latest file?  I have some Windows batch skill but no programming skills :(  Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after downloading all files, try this:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /a-d /b /od "FILENAME_*.txt.pgp"') do set "recent=%%~a"
copy "%recent%" "target"
```

Comment: Thank you!  That worked for me.  Does checking the green box give you credit?